# How to open a terminal at startup?

Tags: boot, terminal

Every time I boot my RPi, I want a terminal open. I'd love to be able to include that in the boot process.

I'm running Raspian.

How can this be done?

Comment: Did you mean in the gui? Or do you need to bypass the login prompt?

Comment: It could also help to know, what system you are running on your pi (Distro and Desktop environment if applicable)

Comment: Since it's raspbian, presumably the DE is LXDE, in which case googling "start-up LXDE" might help, eg. http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=111   I'm not an LXDE user so I can't confirm any of that tho.

Answer (score 3):

You question does not specify whether by 'terminal' you mean the classic terminal
or a graphical session with XTerm opening up automatically.

I'm going to assume the first.

If you're using `wheezy`you can log in automatically by editing `/etc/inittab`

Search for the line:

```
1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

Add a hash tag in front of it

```
#1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

This will disable the line. Next you need to add a new entry:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Where `pi` is the username of the account you want to use for automatic log in.
Note that this bypasses security, allowing access to your PI without the password of the user.

Comment: `inittab` does not exist in `stretch`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of the file /etc/grub/grub.cong and save it to your home folder
2. Now open the file using any text editor (I prefer nano) and find the line that says **quiet splash**
3. Add **text** after **quiet splash**. Now it look like **quiet splash text**
4. Save the file
5. Reboot

If you want to revert, just redo the above steps and remove **text**

Comment: I suspect this is off-topic - The Raspberry Pi does/can not **use** grub AFAICT...

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered for if you're talking about just booeting into a tty instead of your DM, so I'll answer how you'd just start your terminal emulator on X startup.

This is just as easy. 
Edit your /home/user/.xinitrc:

```
exec gnome-terminal &
```

and add the above line. Replace gnome-terminal with your term of choice. The ampersand is to make it execute and send to the background so it doesn't lock up X when it starts.